# Object doesn't support this property or method javascript error in IE6 only

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-6

I've searched the internet and this great stackoverflow.com site particularly, but cannot help myself. I am not very experienced programmer and a friend of mine asked me to fix the bug that is on IE6 only. It works on FF, IE7/8, Opera.
Here is the PART of the code that gives error message on IE6:

```
(function(d, n, r) {
  var ie, jscript, settings = {};
  function add(element, type, listener) { element.addEventListener(type, listener, false); };
  function remove(element, type, listener) { element.removeEventListener(type, listener, false); };
  var l = {change:[], ready:[], load:[]};
  a11y = function(f) {
    a11y.change(f);
  };
})
(self.document, self.navigator);
```

The error is on line 7: **a11y.change(f);**  All other browsers are OK, just IE6. I am not author of the script, just trying to fix this. Can anybody help, please? There must be some problem with function declaration or...?

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: there is a lot of code here that seems irrelevant to the error and some code missing from the example. Can you provide a bit more context around what this code is trying to do?

Comment: any code with variable names like 'a11y' has got to make you nervous :-)

Answer (score 1):

The example looks pretty confused there is a lot of code there that looks to be a distraction.

From what I can see the problem is in this code:

```
a11y = function(f) {
    a11y.change(f);
};
```

Here you are defining a new function called a11y and inside the definition of that function you are calling a method 'change' on the function a11y being defined. I'm surprised that works in any browser.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments. I decided to supply the URL of the test page. Here it is: http://www.apbsystems.com/awareness/sco1.html There is a javascript here: http://www.apbsystems.com/awareness/base/js/a11y/a11y.js There are more scripts there but I suppose this is the script that is causing the problem. The error I get is "Object doesn't support this property or method" in IE6. Thank you for all your effort. I am not sure what all the script means. I've spent two days trying to find out. Basicly it opens a window ...

Answer (score 1):

For me it throws an error in IE7 and IE8 as well.

It reports the error line number as line 4 (line 3 in IE6 but IE6 is always off by one). 
That indicates that the error is in:

```
function add(element, type, listener) { element.addEventListener(type, listener, false); };
```

which isn't surprising since IE doesn't implement addEventListener.  The equivalent call on IE is:

```
element.attachEvent("on" + type, listener)
```

It looks like the page is using jQuery, so you should probably use jQuery methods for this.
Instead of calling

```
add(element, type, listener)
```

you could call

```
$(element).bind(type, listener)
```

You would also need to fix the "remove" function in line 5.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help. As suggested by Sean Hogan, the problem was that IE doesn't implement addEventListener. I found similar fix somewhere on the internet and it worked for me.

```
  function add(element, type, listener) {
      remove(element, type, listener);
      element.attachEvent("on"+ type, listener);
  };
  function remove(element, type, listener) {
      element.detachEvent("on"+ type, listener);
  };
  settings.jscript = jscript = @_jscript_version;
  settings.ie = ie = parseFloat(n.userAgent.split("MSIE ")[1]);
   if (d && d.execCommand) {
    try { d.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache",false, true); }
    catch (e) { }
  }
```

Thanks again!